# Parsing Multiple JSON results into one file

Tags: json, excel

I have a list of 300 urls that provide a query result in JSON format. I need to take that list and parse it into one file that Excel can read and create a table from. The schema is the same for all results, so all I need is all of the output from each link in one file. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are you asking how to merge multiple json data into one ? Or are you asking how to write this json datas to a file ? Or are you asking both ?

Comment: This really isnt a question for SO but google "json to excel online" and you'll find a ton of options that meet your needs, unless your actually want to do this programmatically, in which case we need more information. LIke the schema

Comment: Java & jQuery in one question seems strange. Did you mean *javascript* and jquery?

Comment: I am looking for a programmatic way to get the JSON results from multiple links in a single file without having to go in and copy and paste each one out.

Answer (score 0):

You will need jackson-databind, jackson-core, jackson-annotaions for the solution below. Make sure the version for all 3 jars are same.

Create a class that has variables similar to the "keys" in JSON.E.g. if JSON is

```
{"name" : "test", "age" : 100}
```

then the class would be:

```
public class User{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age= age;
    }
}
```

The main method would be:

```
import User;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    User userObj = mapper.readValue(new URL("http://test.com"), User.class);
}
```

For multiple urls, create a list of objects of User class and then store in excel.

Try link: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

For JSON, you need to define Class like the first answer above. So in case JSON has a complicated structure, defining Class is also a pressure. I recommend you should use a regular expression for JSON.

```
String pattern = "[\\h\\v\\u005B\\u005D\\u007B\\u007D\\u002C\\u003A]*[\\u005B\\u005D\\u007B\\u007D\\u002C\\u003A][\\h\\v\\u005B\\u005D\\u007B\\u007D\\u002C\\u003A]*|"
                        // String type
                        + "(?:[\\u0022][^\\u0022]*[\\u0022])|"
                        // Numeric type
                        + "[0-9.e-]+|"
                        // Boolean type and null for numeric type
                        + "(?:(?i)true|false|null)";
```

You may doubt if the regex above works, then visit here(myblog) at [www.mysplitter.com](http://www.mysplitter.com) and test your code (not commercial stuff), and the whole source(very simple to understand) is here [enter link description here](https://github.com/AndrewKang85/JSON).